# powershell regex replace string from column in csv file

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I need to extract values from a csv file in powershell.
Here a sample of the CSV file:

```
"1","ANYDATA-481190-131","<ul>
<li><strong>487410-131</strong> (prateado)</li>
<li><strong>502478-131</strong></li>
<li><strong>555996-131</strong> (prateado)</li>
<li><strong>AEQT6T11110</strong></li>
<li><strong>AEQT6T00210</strong></li>
</ul>"
```

I need to extract the values between tags `<strong>` and `</strong>` and put them separated with a comma, in a new CSV file like this:

```
"1","ANYDATA-481190-131","487410-131, 502478-131, 555996-131, AEQT6T11110, AEQT6T00210"
```

EDIT:

here is the answer for future searchs:

```
import-csv $CSV -delimiter "," -Header 1,2,3 | Select '1','2',@{n='3';e={[regex]::Matches(($_.3).Split("`n"),"(?<=<strong>)(.*?)(?=</strong>)").Value -join ", "}} | Export-csv $CSV2 -Encoding UTF8 -Notype
```

For 3 columns named 1, 2 and 3 where $CSV is the original CSV File and $CSV2 the destination file,

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a script writing service.  Please post what code you have tried and people will be more likely to help you out

Comment: @Jorge - Your result doesn't match your input. I assume ANYDATA should be PORTECLADO?!

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers you right my mistake, just change some number s to be diferent from real data, now it's correct :)

Comment: I have no experience with the powershell regex engine but this seems to work in regex101.com: `("[^<,"]+)|([^>\n]+(?=<))|\n|.*<strong>|<\/strong\>.*|<\/?ul>`. See the regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/ZZqHc6/1

Answer (score 0):

May do it without a regular expression?

```
ConvertFrom-Csv @'
"1", "ANYDATA-481190-131", "<ul>
<li><strong>487410-131</strong> (prateado)</li>
<li><strong>502478-131</strong></li>
<li><strong>555996-131</strong> (prateado)</li>
<li><strong>AEQT6T11110</strong></li>
<li><strong>AEQT6T00210</strong></li>
</ul>"
'@ -Header 1, 2, 3 -Delimiter ','|
  Select-Object '1', '2', @{
    n='3'
    e={
      $ofs=','
      """$(
        [xml]$_.3|
          Select-Object -ExpandProperty ul|
          Select-Object -ExpandProperty li|
          Select-Object -ExpandProperty strong
      )"""
    }
  }
```

```
1 2                  3                                                       
- -                  -                                                       
1 ANYDATA-481190-131 "487410-131,502478-131,555996-131,AEQT6T11110,AEQT6T00210"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFda4MwFIbv/RWHIKQFM40frYKWStuxq30wb8YYw63Z5ohGou1a1v52F1QG3cYwFydv3vPknHyU4oPJ6o1x3jQLUWyZrM@lyMmi2sIca4giA1B8ebeMk5i4PqWBRajTuuGGz7SQZ7OwqqUoXmeuP3Vpmw7N3oJRKdOapWsxDk2FnvCeZbtT/4T/A/K8IJgMLxqvbpJJQtWw/qnaUZZl/6ZMdS2k4TmQC9WCSaAG2AY4QJaMZ3lWKwsb@KAB3DLOnmty9fSuJsAUG4BtFeafKglQRNjBrWJR5wDo4qWK1PZ@iRDSR70GuN/l/EF/PHMO39bPJmS1K9NifS1Fqb5qDxs@nOXZcLZ7kx4fq2O28qjisWm@AA)